# jquery validaton remove message and change style of the labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation. Using the onfocus function.

However I want to remove the error message and merely style the appropriate labels in the form.

Im having trouble understanding what I need to add to this:

```
jQuery('form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(e) {
    this.element(e);       
 }
});
```

in order to make this happen.

I have tried to do this:

```
jQuery('form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(){ },

    onfocusout: function(e) {
    this.element(e);
    jQuery(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
    .addclass=("error");
}
});
```

but receiving: "element is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

> However I want to remove the error message and merely style the appropriate labels in the form.

Your approach is flawed.  `onfocusout` merely controls the event itself and would never be used to control the elements' style.  That's because the validation is triggered by many events in addition to `onfocusout`.

---

If you want to suppress the error messages, set the `errorPlacement` option to `return false`.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    return false;
}
```

If you want to style the elements, simply use the default classes set by the plugin within your CSS.  `error` is applied to the data input elements and message labels when they fail validation and `valid` is applied when they pass.  Since these same classes are also applied to both, you'll need to be specific with your CSS selectors.

```
input.error {
    /* this is the input element when it fails validation */
}

input.valid {
    /* this is the input element when it passes validation */
}

label.error {
    /* this is the error message element when there is an error */
    /* by default, the message is hidden after the element passes validation */
}
```

If you want to change how classes are applied on pass/fail of validation, then use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options.

```
highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    }
},
unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    }
}
```

Those are the defaults, simply add lines to apply classes to your other `label` elements.